# Android MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED not called in release mode

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have an app update receiver which is running fine in debug apk. but after release and update with Google Play build or already installed release build, it's not getting called.

Receiver entry in manifest file is

```
<receiver android:name=".receiver.AppUpdateReceiver">
                <intent-filter android:priority="100">
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
```

and Receiver class is

```
public class AppUpdateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        try {
            String action = intent.getAction();

            if (action != null && TextUtils.equals(action, Intent.ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED)) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            CTAnalytics.sendExceptionToServer("AppUpdateReceiver onReceive error:", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks about right. I'm not sure why there's a need to specify 'android:priority'?

Try removing `android:priority` and make your receiver `exported` (I think it should be so by default, since you're specifying an intent-filter). So something like:

```
<receiver android:name=".receiver.AppUpdateReceiver"
          android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
            </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: It's called in debug mode via android studio, but not in release mode.

Comment: AFAICT, the code looks correct to me. My other guess would be:
1) Either Toast is not working (that can happen sometimes), perhaps try logging it instead.
2) Or, this receiver is probably disabled (programatically)
3) Or, if you are testing it on a debug build (which you are probably not based on the title), then the version code does not increments, so Android platform perhaps does not treat it as PACKAGE_REPLACED

Comment: It is very likely a problem with your toast - Check if notifications are enabled for your app (if disabled, then Toasts won't show up). Second, in Toast#makeText try replacing Context with ApplicationContext. Per documentation, context in Toast should generally be an ApplicationContext or Activity context - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#makeText(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20int)